# Query tuning performance

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-tuning

I want to optimize my query, which is as follows, it returns the correct results but I feel like I'm doing something wrong or could do it in less steps, my query looks like this.

```
Select /*+ Parallel 8 */
    Mes, Score, Solucion, Ruta, Rango_Monto, Conteo, 
    sum(Conteo) over(partition by Mes, Score, Ruta, Rango_ Monto order by Mes, Score, Ruta, Rango_Monto) TotalCountSol,
    round((Conteo / sum(Conteo) over(partition by Mes, Score, Ruta, Rango_Monto order by Mes, Score, Ruta, Rango_Monto)) * 100, 2) ||'%' "%"
from
    (Select 
         Mes, Score, Solucion, Ruta,
         case
            when Monto <= 2000 then '<2000'
            when Monto between 2001 and 3000 then '2to3k'
            when Monto between 3001 and 4000 then '3to4k'
            when Monto between 4001 and 5000 then '4to5k'
            when Monto between 5001 and 10000 then '5to10k'
            else '10k+'
         end Rango_Monto,
         count(1) Conteo
     from
         (select /*+ Parallel 16 */
              Mes, Score, PNR_ID, Ruta, Solucion,
              sum(case 
                     when Moneda = 'USD' then ((Monto_Total)*19)
                     else Monto_Total
                  end) Monto
          from 
              (select /*+ parallel(h,8) */ 
                   extract(month from h.ts_0002) Mes,
                   case
                      when h.SCORING1_SCORE between 2000 and 3000 then '2k-3k'
                      when h.SCORING1_SCORE between 3000 and 5000 then '3k-5k'
                      when h.SCORING1_SCORE between 5000 and 10000 then '5k-10k'
                      when h.SCORING1_SCORE between 10000 and 50000 then '10k-50k'
                      when h.SCORING1_SCORE between 50000 and 75000 then '50k-75k'
                      when h.SCORING1_SCORE >= 75000 then '75k+'
                   end Score,
                   h.transaction_id PNR_ID,
                   h.text_0338 || h.text_0208 Ruta,
                   case
                      when h.resolution1_id in ('5237260000000000003', '5237260000000000004') then 'Allowed'
                      when h.resolution1_id is null then 'Nulo'
                      else 'Fraude'
                   end Solucion,
                   d.det_text_0053 Moneda,
                   d.det_numeric_0016 Monto_Total
               from 
                   data_headers1_hist h,
                   data_details1_hist d
               where
                   h.id = d.data_header_id
                   and h.scoring1_score > 2000
                   and h.virtual_table_id = '5237260000000002621'
                   and TO_CHAR(h.ts_0002, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') >= '2016/05/01 00:00:00'
                   and TO_CHAR(h.ts_0002, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') <= '2016/05/31 23:59:59'
                   and d.det_text_0019 in ('APPROVED') --Respuesta banco Emisor
                   and SCORING1_RULES_TRIPPED LIKE '%5237260000000390676:500%'
                   --and h.transaction_id = 'CYYPHA__280716'
                   /*and h.text_0338 = 'CUN'
                     and h.text_0208 = 'MEX'*/
                   --and h.text_0338 || h.text_0208 in ('CUNMEX','MEXCUN')
              )
         group by
             Mes, Score, PNR_ID, Ruta, Solucion) 
     group by
         Mes, Score, Solucion, Ruta,
         case
            when Monto <= 2000 then '<2000'
            when Monto between 2001 and 3000 then '2to3k'
            when Monto between 3001 and 4000 then '3to4k'
            when Monto between 4001 and 5000 then '4to5k'
            when Monto between 5001 and 10000 then '5to10k'
            else '10k+'
         end)
order by
    Mes, Score, Rango_Monto, Ruta, Solucion
;
```

As you can see I have to do query by subquery, but when I try to move the arithmetic operations and the groups it messes up my results.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Only the use of the syntax Join? I was more concerned about the subqueries and the arithmetics in it....

Comment: Before diving too deep into it: why is the label '<2000' when the condition is <=2000? That makes zero sense to me. Then: in the FROM clause in the definition of `Score`, you have overlapping `between` conditions - should those be between 2001 and 3000, between 3001 and 4000 etc.?

Comment: It would help tremendously if in addition to (not "instead of"!) what you posted you would describe briefly your tables, with column names and data types (only the columns needed to help you solve the problem), and state the problem requirement and a small sample of input data and desired output. Some of that can be guessed (reverse engineered) from your query, but that takes extra effort which shouldn't be necessary. And if you choose to add that information (please do!), add it to your post, not in a Comment.